# How to optimize specific vba code speed?

Tags: vba, excel

we used this VBA code mainly to hide blank rows & unhide non-blank rows, after that the second code sort the rows by a defined column value once the worksheet activated. This process take too much time with this code, could any one help me optimize this code and make it faster? (the worksheet contain an average of 500 rows).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
HideRows
Sortingrisk
End Sub

Sub HideRows()
Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
Dim strVal As String

   Set rRange = Worksheets(12).Range("A10:A500")

    For Each rCell In rRange
      strVal = rCell
      rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = strVal = vbNullString
    Next rCell
End Sub

Sub Sortingrisk()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort. _
      SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort. _
      SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G10:G1000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
      xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Implementation Plan").AutoFilter.Sort
     .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What du you call "too much time" ? it look really simple and shouldn't take more then a second

Comment: it takes around 20 sec actually :(

Comment: Yeah, I do the test on 4k lines, it takes a while. Try with the solution I gave, it was far better

Answer (score 1):

Insert this at the start of your `Sub`:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And this just before `End Sub`:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Worksheets(12).Range("A10:A500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HiddenRows take an eternity. Try with

```
Sub HideRows()
    Worksheets(12).Range("A10:A500").Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From a programming perspective, you should hide your entire range without using a loop.  You can also optimize the run-time environment, with application properties being the first place to start.

Usually

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

is the most important line for speeding up a macro that's manipulating spreadsheet content.

Followed by

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

which can be useful if your macro is triggering recalculation. I always hesitate to alter the calculation state from automatic though, since you risk leaving you spreadsheet in manual mode if the macro fails, and that can be very dangerous, especially if someone else who doesn't know about the macro is using it.

I would not disable DisplayStatusBar or EnableEvents.  You stand very little to gain as far as speed and a lot to loose as far as functionality.

Here is an example of your code streamlined a little more and using a manual calculation state that will safely reset back to auto on a non-fatal error.  You may want to consider removing the manual state or constructing additional error handling.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
HideRows Me
SortingRisk Range("G10:G1000")
End Sub
Sub HideRows(ByRef w As Worksheet)
w.Range("A10:A500").Rows.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub SortingRisk2(ByRef R As Range)
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
On Error GoTo term
Dim F As AutoFilter
With R.Worksheet
    If .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        R.AutoFilter
    End If
    Set F = R.Worksheet.AutoFilter
    F.Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With

With F.Sort
    .SortFields.Add _
       Key:=R, _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=xlDescending, _
       DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

term:
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
If Err > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: Macro has terminated. Verify that Workbook Calculation
state is in auto."
End If
End Sub
```